# Password protecting a single file with nginx

Tags: authentication, nginx

My location block in trying to password protect a file say `admin.php` is not working.Below is my nginx configuration

```
location = /admin.php {
             root /var/www/site.com/public_html/www;
             index index.php index.html index.htm;
             auth_basic            "Restricted Area";
             auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/site.com/public_html/htpasswd;
        }

location ~* \.php$ { 
    root /var/www/site.com/public_html/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

I tried to  change `location = /admin.php {` to  `location ~/admin\.php$ {` or `location  /admin.php {` but none of them worked

The url of the admin.php is : https://mysite.com/admin.php

And yes i did reload nginx after each try

Kind Regards

Answer (score 6):

I'm a little late, but this is the rule you're looking for:

```
location ~ /admin\.php$ {
    auth_basic "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
    root /var/www/site.com/public_html/www;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

You need to include your fastcgi processing in the location block for the PHP file. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Lot of late. Thanks for the code, hope it helps for me, ill test it out:)

Comment: Thanks. Found it the hard way that I had to include the fastcgi block all over again inside this location block! It's included in my broader server block and it should be inherited here too!

Comment: Question: why are you including `root` again for a single file?